# Display marker in react-mapbox-gl with Feature and Layers

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I'm using the example code that's on the "alex3165/react-mapbox-gl" GitHub repo. Not the example folder but the Getting Started example. The map shows but the marker just doesn't show. Not sure what I am dong wrong. Been cracking my head around such a basic thing but just cant solve it. I have looked at previous questions on the net around this topic but none is a solution for me. Here is my code and my dependencies.  Help will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance guys.

PACKAGE JSON

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "mapbox-gl": "^1.13.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-mapbox-gl": "^5.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
```

CODE:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import ReactMapboxGl, { Layer, Feature, Marker } from "react-mapbox-gl";
const Map = ReactMapboxGl({
  accessToken: "<my access token goes here>",
});

function App() {
  const [Zoom, setZoom] = useState(10);
  const [coordinates, setcoordinates] = useState([28.0473197, -26.2041059]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Map
        center={coordinates}
        zoom={[Zoom]}
        // eslint-disable-next-line react/style-prop-object
        style="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
        containerStyle={{
          height: "100vh",
          width: "100vw",
        }}
      >
        <Layer type="symbol" id="marker" layout={{ "icon-image": "marker-15" }}>
          <Feature coordinates={[28.0473197, -26.2041059]} />
        </Layer>
      </Map>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Something has changed in v5.0.0, but they haven't updated the documentation and nobody cares. If you downgrade to v4.8.6, you should see the marker. Though I'm not sure if marker-15 exists in the streets-v9 style.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr  Anatoly Sukhanov , your solution works. Much appreciated